# Quarkus (1.10.4/1.11.0) build. no default datasource found

Tags: hibernate, exception, build, datasource, quarkus

I am trying to migrate an existing Quarkus (1.7.5) project to Quarkus version 1.11.0
I can build althrough until version 1.10.3. From version 1.10.4 during the build I get the exception below (It is a new feature looking at the changlog  #13894 - Throw an exception when model classes and no datasource)

However I am declaring datasources in the application properties according to the documentation using jdbc postgres:
https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm

Had a glimpse at agroal with an quarkus-extension.yaml, didn't help though

What am I missing? Thankful for any Pointers

application.properties

```
..further declarations
...
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.username=my_user
quarkus.datasource.password=my_password
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase
...
..further declarations
```

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.11.0.Final:build (default) on project isp-testArch11-core: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]         [error]: Build step io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.deployment.HibernateOrmProcessor#configurationDescriptorBuilding threw an exception: io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.ConfigurationException: Model classes are defined for the default persistence unit but no default datasource found: the default EntityManagerFactory will not be created.
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.deployment.HibernateOrmProcessor.handleHibernateORMWithNoPersistenceXml(HibernateOrmProcessor.java:697)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.deployment.HibernateOrmProcessor.configurationDescriptorBuilding(HibernateOrmProcessor.java:310)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:972)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2415)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :isp-testArch11-core
```

Versions until 1.10.3 do work.
Using:

Maven 3.6.3

Java 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out what the issue was.

Maven ignored application.properties because in the pom.xml, in the build job, there are addiotional resources declared.

If you do NOT delcare resources, it looks in the default directories like src/main/recources

If you do declare any additional resources you have to declare src/main/recources explicitly as well.

```
<build>
 <finalName>${project.parent.artifactId}</finalName>
 <resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>../additional_stuff</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.*</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
  <resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.*</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
...
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

this question is related a fix on quarkus. https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/14930

The team will change the error message, here is the commit
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/commit/40b6345f0f71e8d585c21d6576ab26920c9b6dc4

To solve it add a "fake" default datasource configuration to your application.properties

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.username=postgres
quarkus.datasource.password=s3cr3t
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.sql=true
```

Another "worst" solution is create a Java repository (Panache) and the entityManager will be "created" (not needed application.properties datasource definitions)

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class FakeRepository implements PanacheRepository<MyJPAEntity> {
   ...not necessay implementation
}
```

Consider that if your are working on a JPA entity library better solution is to remove your quarkus-hibernate-orm-* dependency on your project and only add javax-persistence.api dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope Helps